# Equivalent of Ruby's prepend in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a software and I have to convert it from Ruby to Python.
It's working great, but there is a feature I need to develop that requires me to use an equivalent of the **prepend** method in Ruby in a pythonic way.

Does this thing exists in Python? How can I implement it?

Let me explain it with some code:

I've got one library, called **LibA**.

In there I have a class **JobHandler**:

```
class JobHandler:
    
    def __init__(self):
        print('JobHandler init constructor')

    def process_message(self, message):
        # Do things with message
        # ...
        # Finally send the message
        send(message)
```

I've got an other library, called LibB, with a class **JobHandling**:

```
class JobHandling:
    
    def __init__(self):
        print('JobHandling init constructor')

    def process_message(self, message):
        # Do things with message
        # ...

        # -> Here in Ruby I can call method super
        ## super
```

These are 2 differents libraries, don't ask why, they just don't do the same.

Now, I'm developing a program, that uses LibA & LibB (those libs are installed into my Pipfile / requirements.txt).

There I've got a new class that looks like this:

```
from LibA.handlers.JobHandler import JobHandler
from LibB.handlers.JobHandling import JobHandling

class ProgramJobHandler(JobHandler):

    # -> Here in Ruby i can use `prepend JobHandling`
    ## prepend JobHandling
    # So everytime my ProgramJobHandler.process_message is called (inherited from JobHandler),
    # it's JobHandling.process_message who is called first

    def __init__(self):
        print('My program job handler constructor')
```

As you can see, the call to ProgramJobHandler.process_message will first call JobHandling.process_message that uses `super` keyword to look up and call the JobHandler.process_message method.

Is there a way to do that in Python, some sort of equivalence of `preprend` ?
I can't use LibA into my LibB, I can only use both in the same program.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything directly equivalent to `prepend` in Python, but in your use case you don't actually need `prepend` at all since `prepend` is only needed when the class you're prepending with (`JobHandling`) needs to be even lower than the class you're prepending to (`ProgramJobHandler`) in the inheritance chain, so that when there is a method name conflict, the method of the former can be called before that of the latter.

But since your own `ProgramJobHandler` class doesn't define `process_message` itself and relies on its parent class `JobHandler` to define it, you can simply make `ProgramJobHandler` inherit both `JobHandling` and `JobHandler` (in that order) so that `JobHandling.process_message` gets called when `ProgramJobHandler.process_message` is called, and `JobHandling.process_message` can then call `super().process_message` to cooperatively pass the baton to the `process_message` method further up the inheritance chain to `JobHandler.process_message`:

```
class JobHandler:
    def process_message(self, message):
        print('JobHandler', message)

class JobHandling:
    def process_message(self, message):
        print('JobHandling', message)
        super().process_message(message)

class ProgramJobHandler(JobHandling, JobHandler):
    pass

ProgramJobHandler().process_message('hi')
```

This outputs:

```
JobHandling hi
JobHandler hi
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DependableTremendousRam

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I ended up with that solution after some tests on my side.